# get element id from array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array which is just id for buttons on mysite. I stead of getting the button id individually, ive put them in an array because I feel it'ld save me a lot of time.

```
var array = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];
for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    var Button = document.getElementById(array[i]);
}
```

My question is how do I get individual button names I can use as reference.

Button.innerhtml just lists all contents of all 3 in d array instead of individually

Comment: Please explain _"how do I get individual button names I can use as reference"_ ? And please do not post same question again!

Comment: I want to generate individual button names to match the ids in the array so I can use that to trigger separate events

Comment: You haven't explained what you are really trying to do with any of this. See [ask] and provide proper problem statement including expected results. Also note that javascript is case sensitive ... check your console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, but I was finally able to solve it using foreach loop.

```
 var array = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];

 array.forEach(function(item, index){

      var item = document.getElementById(item);

 Item.onclick = run function;


  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript :

```
<script>
    var buttons = ['home','about','contact'];

    var btns = "";
    for(i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
       btns +="<input type='button' id='+buttons[i]+' value='"+buttons[i]+"'/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("mybuttons").innerHTML=btns;
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<div id="mybuttons"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];

 for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   document.getElementById(array[i]).value = array[i];
   document.getElementById(array[i]).innerHTML = array[i];// If you want the text on the button
 }
```

I think you want to do something like this. This will loop over the array and assign the value of that array item to the button.

Comment: Exactly, almost there..but can I get the numerical index of the array like button[i] = document.getElementById(array[i]);

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi Yes, `document.getElementById(array[i]).innerHTML = i;` will start at 0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need here, but you can dynamically manipulate your data the way you are trying to.

**HTML**

```
<button id="home">home</button>
<button id="about">about</button>
<button id="contact">contact</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var array = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];
var myButtons = [];

for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    var button = document.getElementById(array[i]);
    button.name = array[i]+'-buttonName';
    button.innerHTML = 'something';
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('you clicked on '+button.name); }, false);
    ....
    myButtons.push(button);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How do I call an onclick for each button. Say I want to do home.onclick but using the array.

Comment: add a event listener for click function: `button.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('clicked! on '+ button.name); }, false);`